# What's the evidence that it is the nitronium cation (NO2+) acting as the attacking electrophile in mixed acid nitration of aromatic compounds (SeAr)

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, synthesis

As per the title, I'm looking as to what is the evidence is that it is the $\ce{NO2+}$ cation acting as the attacking electrophile in an electrophillic aromatic substitution reaction involving the 'mixed acid' reagents of $\ce{H2SO4 + HNO3}$

---

I have considered the following although I feel as if other explanations exist and doesn't really specifically tackle the question:

The generation of the electrophile is as follows

$$\ce{2 H2SO4 + HNO3 -> H3O+ + NO2+ + 2 HSO4-}$$

Of which has been shown to be valid via spectroscopy methods & being consistent with the expected freezing-point depression. The $\ce{NO2+}$ cation can be trapped within unreactive anions (such as $\ce{BF4-},\ce{PF6-}$) to form salts which can then themselves act as nitrating agents to obtain the same nitration reaction product.

Comment: Water will be protonated to $\ce{H3O+}$ in this medium.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are some alternatives that you have considered?