Why is NO2+ an electrophile
When we make the structure of NO2+ the octet seem to be complete to me...

As nitrogen gains 4 extra electrons due to the covalent bond and loses one due to the positive charge, which sums up to 8 electrons. That is why I think that the octet is complete. So how does NO2+ behave like an electrophile, as it does not seem to be electron deficient.
Please correct me where I went wrong in my interpretation.

The nitrogen having + charge is a favorable place for attack by a nucleophile. Its almost like a carbonyl carbon but even better with a +

But why would nitrogen try to break its own octet by accepting electrons

Unanswered duplicate: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/126066/why-is-nitronium-ion-an-electrophile

Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86301/whats-the-evidence-that-it-is-the-nitronium-cation-no2-acting-as-the-attacki

Both O atoms are helping the central N to be the good electrophil by pulling electron density and finally an electron itself.

@Poutnik that seems to be a valid explanation. Thank you for helping.

There is a positive charge, which is per se always electrophile.
And why is the charge located at N? Because N is less electronegative than O.
The same is true for the similar CO2, which has a partial positive charge at C.

Do you mind adding some more effort in your "answer"? What is wrong molecule you speak of? Answer should be self contained and reference should be added. Otherwise, it stands as a simple comment.

It's a bit thin for an answer, but it does cover the biggest point. It would be nice to have a few words on why a full octet is not the measure, but otherwise it's ok. And welcome to Chemistry.se!

@Martin-マーチン do you have a satisfactory explanation for why the octet is not affecting the electrophilic nature?? If yes, then I would be very grateful to know the correct explanation.

Why do you think that the octett rule can help you to decide if a molecule is an electrophile? The octett rule is fulfilled almost always.

Because in most of the cases atoms having a lone pair act an a nucleophile and atoms having an incomplete octet act as an electrophile..
But there seems to be an exception in this case which I am not able to find, thats why I want to know what is the phenomenon because of which it is an electrophile.

"atoms having an incomplete octet act as an electrophile."
This is normally only the case when it has less than 4 valence electrons, e.g. BH3.
